# Upgrade DLLs of MSM file through patch/hotfix created using windows installer wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

Hi We have a scenario here:

We deployed DLLs in the system through setup installer.

Now we upgraded the DLLs and created `msm` file for that.

Now want to deploy the upgraded DLL through patch/hotfix installer instead of setup installer.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you rebuild the MSI file with the new merge module and then use that against the original MSI file to create a patch. It's the same as if the file was not in a merge module - you still increment its file version, rebuild the MSI and then create a patch. The Windows SDK method would be to use MsiMsp.exe and a .PCP  file with options and references to the old and new MSI administrative images. This should help:

http://trentm.com/2007/05/building-msi-patch-packages-msp-with-wix.html

WiX can do patching too,

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/wix_patching.html

Comment: Hi, I Created a patch. but If I apply patch, updates dlls (of the MSM file) are not updating in the system after patch update.

Comment: The answer here may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215121/how-to-force-a-file-update-in-patch-dynamic-link-unversioned but if you incremented the file version and the patch isn't replacing files then a verbose log may tell you why, otherwise I'd start a new question about why a patch won't update files if you have no success.